# What sort of hinge is this?

Tags: hinges, custom-cabinetry

Can someone tell me what sort of hinge this is?

[image: Suspect Hinge]

All the cabinet hinges I can find are 180deg+ when open, whereas this is only 90deg.

They are on a set of built-in wardrobes that were here when we moved into our house. Unfortunately, one of the doors had a dirty great mirror stuck on it which is slowly killing the hinges. That door currently has only three out of five hinges actually connected - the others have broken and need replacing before the door drops off on my wife's foot.

Looking for somewhere I can source these in the UK.

Comment: Can you post what the text in the hinge body is?

Comment: @MichaelKaras Heh. Didn't think of actually looking at that. It's **GRASS US. PAT. No: RE 34.995**. So it's made by GRASS Inc. I've found a document that mentions this number in connection with US Pat #5,604,956, but doesn't appear to show this type (where the baseplate mounts on the face)

Comment: If hinges are breaking, perhaps a heavier-duty hinge would be appropriate?

Comment: @Technophile: I agree that heavier-duty hinges would be a better option, but unfortunately I don't have too many choices here. That said, they have lasted the ten years we've been in the house and probably ten more before. The four other doors (without a mirror on them) are also fine, so the situation is not that bad. I do have a Forstner bit though, and will be adding extra hinges to take the increased load.

Comment: Google for "face frame hinge UK". Note examples like ["Blum 120"](http://www.trade-hinges.co.uk/blum-120-face-frame-hinge-212-p.asp)

Comment: Thanks - that was the phrase I was missing - "Face Frame Hinge".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell these appear to be hinges made by GRASS. A look at an online retailer seems to point to these hinges:

http://www.hardwaresource.com/hinges/cabinet-hinges/blum-european-hinges-grass-european-hinges/grass-european-hinges/grass-830-and-831-hinges

However the above appear to be obsolete and they recommend replacing with these hinges:

http://www.hardwaresource.com/index.php?l=product_detail&p=3987

[image]

These appear to require two separate order parts.

Comment: These style hinges often are stocked as two separate parts.The cabinet hardware has multiple ways of attaching, the above piece sets in a Forstner bit produced pocket in the door and will have mechanisms for 90, 135, 180 degree opening, etc.. It's mix and match to get the desired end result.

Comment: Also, these hinges are often referred to as Blum or Compact European Style cabinet hinges. Blum and Grass are common manufacturers.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the hinge in your photo: [Grass hinge](http://www.hardwaresource.com/hinges/cabinet-hinges/blum-european-hinges-grass-european-hinges/grass-european-hinges/grass-830-and-831-hinges) .It is labeled as a #830 or 831.